# ¿Cómo puedo ingresar un registro a un modelo cuando un atributo a llenar es una clave foránea.? - IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Tengo la siguiente estructura de mi proyecto:

He querido enunciar todo el contexto de negocio de mi aplicación (al menos el que le compete al problema que tengo) para ilustrar mejor la situación. Disculpas de antemano por lo largo del post, es por ello.

Dos aplicaciones llamadas userprofile y rbsessions

```
project
    userprofile
        models.py
    rbsessions
        models.py
```

En userprofile/models.py estoy gestionando el esquema de usuarios a través de los siguientes modelos: `User`,`MedicalProfile`,`PatientProfile` y `TherapistProfile`. 
Lo que quiere decir que en mi sistema existen usuarios que son médicos, que son pacientes y que son terapeutas

Cuando yo creo un usuario via django admin, debo asociarle alguno de estos atributos:

- is_medical: Sera un usuario médico y si lo selecciono al crearlo, se creará automáticamente un perfil de ese usuario en el modelo MedicalProfile
- is_patient: Sera un usuario paciente y si lo selecciono al crearlo, se creará automáticamente un perfil de ese usuario en el modelo PatientProfile
- is_therapist: Sera un usuario terapeuta y si lo selecciono al crearlo, se creará automáticamente un perfil de ese usuario en el modelo TherapistProfile

Se entiende que cuando un usuario paciente es creado en el sistema, es porque va a recibir sesiones de terapia o citas medicas.
**(Los datos de una sesion de terapia los detallaré mas adelante en una clase llamada Session)**

Cuando un usuario paciente es creado, quiero que de manera automática además de su perfil `PatientProfile` (el cual ya se crea), se cree una instancia de la clase `Session` (la detallo mas adelante) lo que significará que tendrá una cita asignada.

(**ver última condición** `elif` e**n el modelo User que presentaré a continuación** )

Acorde a lo anterior, los modelos `User`, `MedicalProfile`, `PatientProfile`, `TherapistProfile` son los siguientes:

- `User` model (`userprofile/models.py`)

  ```
  from __future__ import unicode_literals
  from django.conf import settings
  from django.utils import timezone
  from datetime import datetime
  from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
  from django.db import models 
  from django.dispatch import receiver
  from django.db.models.signals import post_save
  from rbsessions.models import Session

  class User(AbstractUser):

      birth_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

      address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)

      phone = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'phone', max_length=25, blank=True)

      is_medical = models.BooleanField(default=False)

      is_therapist = models.BooleanField(default=False)

      is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)

      slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)

      photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', blank = False)

  #Sobreescribo el metodo save para la creacion de cada perfil de usuario
      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         user = super(User, self).save( *args, **kwargs)

          # Creating and user with medical, patient and therapist profiles
          if self.is_medical and not MedicalProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
              and self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
              and self.is_therapist and not TherapistProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():

              medical_profile=MedicalProfile(user=self).save()
              patient_profile=PatientProfile(user=self).save()
              therapist_profile=TherapistProfile(user=self).save()


          # Creating and user with medical and patient profiles
          elif self.is_medical and not MedicalProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
          and self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():

              medical_profile=MedicalProfile(user=self).save()
              patient_profile=PatientProfile(user=self).save()

          # Creating and user with medical and therapist profiles
          elif self.is_medical and not MedicalProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
          and self.is_therapist and not TherapistProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():

              medical_profile=MedicalProfile(user=self).save()
              therapist_profile=TherapistProfile(user=self).save()

          # Creating and user with physiotherapist and patient profiles
          elif self.is_therapist and not TherapistProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists()\
          and self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():

              therapist_profile = TherapistProfile(user=self).save()
              patient_profile = PatientProfile(user=self).save()

          # Creating and user with medical profile
          elif self.is_medical and not MedicalProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
              profile = MedicalProfile(user=self)
              profile.save()

          # Creating and user with patient profile ---Here---
          elif self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
              profile = PatientProfile(user=self)
              profile.save()

          #Quiero crear una instancia de una sesión de rehabilitacion para cuando se crea un paciente
              session = Session()
              session.description = 'This is a rehabilitation session for a patient. This register session ' \
                            'will be completed for the medical personal
              session.status = 'PLA'
              session.participants = 'By define'
              session.period = 'By define'
              session.game_levels = 'By define'
              session.iterations = 0
              session.movements = 'By define'
              session.games = 'By define'
              session.medical = MedicalProfile.objects.create(user=self)
              session.therapist = TherapistProfile.objects.create(user=self)
              session.patient = PatientProfile.objects.create(user=self)
              session.save()


      class Meta:
          db_table = 'auth_user'
  ```
- `MedicalProfile` model (`userprofile/models.py`)

  ```
  class MedicalProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
      specialty = models.CharField(max_length=64)
      def __str__(self):
          return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
  ```
- `PatientProfile` model (`userprofile/models.py`)

  ```
  class PatientProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
      blood_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=False)
      care_provider = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
      time_of_evolution = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
      affected_limb = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
      diagnostic = models.TextField(blank=True)
      managing_organization = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)

      def __str__(self):
          return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
  ```
- `TherapistProfile` model (`userprofile/models.py`)

  ```
  class TherapistProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
      specialty = models.CharField(max_length=64)

      def __str__(self):
          return '%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
  ```

**Aplicación rbsessions**

Comentaba al inicio que tengo otra aplicación llamada `rbsessions` desde la cual se gestionarán las sesiones de terapia o rehabilitación de los pacientes, por lo que existe un modelo llamado Sessions.

- `Sessions` model (rbsessions/models.py)

  ```
  from django.db import models
  from django.utils import timezone

  # Create your models here.
  class Session(models.Model):

      STATUS_PLANNED = 'PLA'
      STATUS_ARRIVED = 'ARR'
      STATUS_IN_PROGRESS = 'PRO'
      STATUS_ON_LEAVE = 'ONL'
      STATUS_FINISHED = 'FIN'
      STATUS_CANCELLED = 'CAN'

      STATUS_CHOICES = (
          (STATUS_PLANNED, u'Planned'),
          (STATUS_ARRIVED, u'Arrived'),
          (STATUS_IN_PROGRESS, u'In progress'),
          (STATUS_FINISHED, u'Finished'),
          (STATUS_CANCELLED, u'Cancelled'),
      )

      description = models.TextField(blank=False)
      date_session = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
      status = models.CharField(max_length=3,
          choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
          default=STATUS_PLANNED)
      participants = models.TextField(blank=False)
      period = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True)
      game_levels = models.TextField(blank=True)
      iterations = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
      movements = models.TextField(blank=False)
      games = models.TextField(blank=False)
      #slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)

      #Claves foráneas.

      medical = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.MedicalProfile')
      patient = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.PatientProfile')
      therapist = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.TherapistProfile')
  ```

Como podemos detallar este modelo tiene tres llaves foráneas que apuntan a los usuarios médico y fisioterapeuta que se encargarán de la sesión y otra al usuario paciente que es el que la llevará a cabo. Mi problema que enunciaré ahora tiene que ver con esto.

Cuando quiero crear un usuario paciente, quiero que automáticamente se le asigne una sesión en donde va a ser atendido. Es decir que se cree para ese usuario paciente que fue registrado, una instancia de la clase `Session`.

Y es así como en `userprofile/models.py` en la clase User (como esta más arriba pero lo indico acá de nuevo), en esta porción de código pregunto:

Si se esta creando un usuario paciente (is_patient checked) creese su perfil en PatientProfile e inmediatamente se crea una instancia de `Session` con todos sus campos o atributos correspondientes:

El código sobre como lo estoy haciendo es asi:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
     ...
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = super(User, self).save( *args, **kwargs)       
    # creating users with  other profiles
    if self.is ...
    ...
    # Creating and user with patient profile
    elif self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
        profile = PatientProfile(user=self)
        profile.save()

        #Creando la instancia Session que sera la sesión de rehabilitación de ese paciente que se esta creando
        session = Session()
        session.description = 'This is a rehabilitation session for a patient. This register session ' \
                              'will be completed for the medical personal'
        session.status = 'PLA'
        session.participants = 'By define'
        session.period = 'By define'
        session.game_levels = 'By define'
        session.iterations = 0
        session.movements = 'By define'
        session.games = 'By define'
        session.medical = MedicalProfile.objects.create(user=self)
        session.therapist = TherapistProfile.objects.create(user=self)
        session.patient = PatientProfile.objects.create(user=self)
        session.save()
```

Cuando via Django admin creo un usuario con el perfil de paciente (`is_patient` checked) me sale esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este `IntegrityError` que obtengo, es porque estoy guardando una instancia de la clase `Session` dentro del override del metodo `save()` que estoy realizando tambien. Y de hecho antes de grabar Session llamo a un .save() en donde grabo el perfil del paciente

Entonces gracias a esos `save()` sucesivos Django graba dos veces el mismo usuario.

Tengo un `.save` dentro de la funcion def `save()` de esta forma

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = super(User, self).save( *args, **kwargs)

```
# Creating and user with patient profile
if self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
    profile = PatientProfile(user=self)
    profile.save()
    #Primer save

    session = Session()
    session.description = 'This is a rehabilitation session for a patient. This register session ' \
                          'will be completed for the medical personal'
    session.status = 'PLA'
    session.participants = 'By define'
    session.period = 'By define'
    session.game_levels = 'By define'
    session.iterations = 0
    session.movements = 'By define'
    session.games = 'By define'
    session.medical = MedicalProfile.objects.create(user=self)
    session.therapist = TherapistProfile.objects.create(user=self)
    session.patient = PatientProfile.objects.create(user=self)
    session.save()
    #Segundo save()
```

***¿Estoy en lo correcto?***

Algo que quize probar acorde a cosas que me habian sugerido y había hecho también antes era que en lugar de grabar la instancia de `Session` de un usuario paciente que se crea dentro del override del metodo `save()`, utilicé un signal `post_save()` para decirle a Django que cuando me cree el usuario paciente, cree su sesión de terapia.

Entonces quité la creación de la sesión de un paciente en el metodo `save()`

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = super(User, self).save( *args, **kwargs)

    # Creating and user with patient profile
    if self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
        profile = PatientProfile(user=self)
        profile.save()
```

Y dije lo siguiente:

```
# Signal for save rehabilitation_session of a patient user
@receiver(post_save, sender = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def creating_rehabilitation_session_patient(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = instance
    #if created:
    if user.is_patient:
        Session.objects.create(description='This is a rehabilitation session for a patient. This register session'
                               'will be completed for the medical personal',
                               status='PLA', participants='By define', period='By define',
                               game_levels='By define', iterations=0, movements='By define',
                               games='By define',)
```

Pero acá me ocurre que no conozco como decirle a Django que en el `Session.objects.create(...)` que estoy haciendo, me incluya los valores de los atributos `medical`, `patient`, `therapist` (**van después de** `games` en el código inmediatamente anterior) que son llaves foráneas de los modelos `MedicalProfile`, `PatientProfile` y `TherapistProfile` que se relacionan con el modelo `Session`

Al parecer con este signal al grabar los datos, no se si funcionará, ya que me sale también un IntegrityError, pero no porque mi usuario ya exista en el sistema (como el anterior), sino porque como no estooy enviando valores a los campos `medical`, `patient`, `therapist` y éstos no aceptan valores nulos entonces no pueden ir vacíos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si la idea de aplicar el signal `post_save()` a mi función `def creating_rehabilitation_session_patient()` resuelva mi problema y en cuyo caso ...

¿cual es la mejor forma de enviarle los parámetros de los campos `medical`, `patient`, `therapist`?

Aunque no se si tal vez una vez que le pueda enviar los campos `medical`, `patient`, `therapist` correctamente me salga también el error de IntegrityError already userprofile exist (el primero que obtuve), dado que finalmente así sea en el override del metodo save() o con un signal, finalmente estoy haciendo un save ... aunque con el signal es despues de ..
No se si mi análisis es correcto.

¿Como puedo lograr esto?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

He modificado acorde a la respuesta que obtuve, los campos `session.medical`, `session.therapist`, `session.patient` en la clase `Session` en `rbsessions/models.py`

Ahora estoy llamando a las funciones que me devuelven el perfil respectivo de cada usuario, de esta manera:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = super(User, self).save( *args, **kwargs)

    # Creating and user with patient profile
    if self.is_patient and not PatientProfile.objects.filter(user=self).exists():
        profile = PatientProfile(user=self)
        profile.save()
        #Primer save

        session = Session()
        session.description = 'This is a rehabilitation session for a patient. This register session ' \
                          'will be completed for the medical personal'
        session.status = 'PLA'
        session.participants = 'By define'
        session.period = 'By define'
        session.game_levels = 'By define'
        session.iterations = 0
        session.movements = 'By define'
        session.games = 'By define'

        #Imrpimo el valor de lo que me retorna get_medical_profile()
        print (self.get_medical_profile())

        session.medical = self.get_medical_profile()
        session.therapist = self.get_therapist_profile()
        session.patient = self.get_patient_profile()
        session.save()
        #Segundo save()
```

Pero al examinar el contenido de lo que me retorna la función `get_medical_profile()`, detallo que le estoy enviando el valor de `None` al momento de crear una instancia de la clase Session

```
[21/Jan/2016 21:40:30] "POST /admin/userprofile/user/add/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[21/Jan/2016 21:40:30] "GET /admin/userprofile/user/26/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 24279
[21/Jan/2016 21:40:30] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3189
None
Internal Server Error: /admin/userprofile/user/26/change/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 541, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 244, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1438, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1378, in changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 991, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/neurorehabilitation-system/userprofile/models.py", line 141, in save
    session.medical = self.get_medical_profile()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 199, in __set__
    (instance._meta.object_name, self.field.name)
ValueError: Cannot assign None: "Session.medical" does not allow null values.
```

Y es normal claro, porque en mis funciones de profiles, inicialmente los profiles respectivos son inicializados a None

```
# We get the profiles user according with their type
    def get_medical_profile(self):
        medical_profile = None
        #medical_profile = MedicalProfile.objects.get(user=self)
        if hasattr(self, 'medicalprofile'):
            medical_profile=self.medicalprofile
        return medical_profile

    def get_patient_profile(self):
        patient_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'patientprofile'):
            patient_profile = self.patientprofile
        return patient_profile

    def get_therapist_profile(self):
        therapist_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'therapistprofile'):
            therapist_profile = self.therapistprofile
        return therapist_profile
```

Creo que al preguntar lo que voy a preguntar ahora tal vez no he acabado de comprender como trabajan las funciones `get` de los `profiles`, dado que estas han sido inicializadas a None pensaría con el objetivo de que cuando no existan las relaciones `OneToOne` no tengamos el error de `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` (¿?)

Intenté cambiar este valor o equivalente por esta linea

```
medical_profile = MedicalProfile.objects.get(self.user.first_name)
```

Pero obtuve esto.

```
AttributeError at /admin/userprofile/user/31/change/
'User' object has no attribute 'user'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/userprofile/user/31/change/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'User' object has no attribute 'user'
Exception Location: /home/bgarcial/workspace/neurorehabilitation-system/userprofile/models.py in get_medical_profile, line 158
Python Executable:  /home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/home/bgarcial/workspace/neurorehabilitation-system',
 '/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/nrb_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 21 Jan 2016 22:19:37 +0000
```

En estos momentos no comprendo como debo manejar el valor retornado de las funciones get_medical_profile, y demás. De pronto puedes explicarme su funcionamiento por favor.
Entre otras cosas porque se pregunta por el atributo de esta forma:

```
if hasattr(self, 'patientprofile'):
```

Gracias y disculpas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy casi seguro que el problema está en esta parte de tu código:

```
session.medical = MedicalProfile.objects.create(user=self)
session.therapist = TherapistProfile.objects.create(user=self)
session.patient = PatientProfile.objects.create(user=self)
```

Estás tratando de crear nuevamente el perfil cuando deberías llamar a las funciones que has creado anteriormente para obtenerlas:

```
session.medical = self.get_medical_profile()
session.therapist = self.get_therapist_profile()
session.patient = self.get_patient_profile()
```

### Actualización

Sobre tu duda:

> Creo que al preguntar lo que voy a preguntar ahora, tal vez no he acabado de comprender como trabajan las funciones get de los profiles, dado que estas han sido inicializadas a None pensaría con el objetivo de que cuando no existan las relaciones OneToOne no tengamos el error de RelatedObjectDoesNotExist (¿?)

Asi es, en las relaciones con `models.OneToOneField` es posible que la relación no exista, es por eso que en una de las respuestas anteriores lo planteé asi. Esto es para que tu puedas validarlo ya que es posible que un usuario no tenga todos los perfiles:

```
if user.get_medical_profile():
    # algo
elif user.get_patient_profile():
    # algo
elif user.get_therapist_profile():
    # algo
else:
    # wtf?
```

El tema es que, corrígeme si me equivoco, que tu modelo `Session` acepta los tres perfiles, pero en ciertos casos es posible que no tengas los tres, por lo tanto considero que tu modelo `Session` debería aceptar nulos en esos campos:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    # ...
    medical = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.MedicalProfile', null=True, blank=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.PatientProfile', null=True, blank=True)
    therapist = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.TherapistProfile', null=True, blank=True)
```

Con este cambio ya no deberías tener problemas usando tus funciones ya que estas retornan `None` cuando el usuario no tiene uno de los perfiles.

Comment: Es cierto, al hacer esto (con lo del objects.create, estoy creandolo de nuevo y no es lo correcto si lo examino con lógica.) Puse un apartado de **ACTUALIZACIÓN** en mi pregunta en relación a las funciones get_profiles de los usuarios, si de pronto me puedes dar una mano porfa. Saludos

Comment: @bgarcial actualizada, espero haber entendio bien el problema

Comment: Si entiendo, incluso pensé en ponerlos como no nulos como tu me indicas a pesar de que aunque creo que por regla de negocio, es mandatorio que una sesión de un paciente tenga estos tres actores. Se podría poner como no nulos y ya el usuario que crea la sesión escogería el medico y el terapeuta cuando llene los datos de la sesión ya que después  de hacer el workflow de registrar un paciente, se debe ir a la sesión que se crea para llenarla con los datos reales. Ahí podrían escoger el médico y el terapeuta para dicha sesión. Esto se que es mas de interacción de usuario que otra cosa.

Comment: Aunque no se si sea una salida facilista, pero tiene lógica, aunque me intriga como ponerlos mandatorios, pero pues tendria que tener una logica de mi aplicación en consultar el listado de los terapeutas y los médicos presentes e ingresar dichas instancias ya existentes (¿?)